# lower bound on $xy/(x+y)?$

Tags: real-analysis

I am looking forward to a lower bound on $x*y/(x+y),$ where both of $x\geq 1$ and $y\geq 1$ are real.

The upper bound on $x*y/(x+y)$ is obvious, for example $x$ or $y$. But a lower bound is not very obvious to me. I want a simple lower bound, which is not very complex.

Could anyone pass some wisdom to me?

Thanks a lot in advance..

Answer (score 6):

Flip it over. After some simplification, we get $\dfrac{1}{y}+\dfrac{1}{x}$. It is not hard to find an **upper** bound for this.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. One obvious lower bound would be \frac{1}{x}+1, which was also suggested by @Avatar and Nick Kidman below... But, this is not what I want...Hmm, let me think how to revise my question....

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{xy}{x+y}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}}$$

So to compute lower bound on this expression is same as computing upper bound on $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}$

Since, $x\geq 1\implies \frac{1}{x}\leq1$ and similarly $\frac{1}{y}\leq 1$

Thus, $$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}\leq 2 $$ $$\implies \frac{xy}{x+y}\geq \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: You mean $\geq \frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

$$ \frac{xy}{x+y}=\frac{(x-1)(y-1)}{x+y}+1-\frac{1}{x+y}\geq 1-\frac{1}{x+y}\geq \frac{1}{2}$$

because $x+y \geq 2 \Rightarrow -\frac{1}{x+y}\geq -\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 2):

The expression is symmetric in $x,y$, so set without loss of generality $y\ge x$. Then you can redefine $y$ as $y=Y\cdot x$, with $Y\ge 1$. The expression becomes a direct product

$$\frac{xy}{x+y} =\frac{x^2Y}{x+xY} = x\cdot\frac{Y}{1+Y},$$

which is linear in x, so clearly $x=1$ is required for a minimum. The minumum of the function $\frac{Y}{1+Y}$ which slowly converges against unity is taken at $y=Y=1$ as well, where it then evaluates to $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks.. but this is not what I want... Let me think how to raise my question properly....

Comment: @LiuYing: Why is this not what you want? It is correct, it is simple.

Answer (score 0):

Thank everyone above. Inspired by your collective intelligence, I came up with a lower bound that I would like to use:

x*y/(x+y)\geq 1/2*min(x,y)

Comment: @Beni Bogosel, hi Beni, I like this one, which has something to do with both x and y...

Comment: The initial expression is symmetric in $x$ and $y$ so without loss of generality, set $y\ge x$. The lower bound you stated is what you get when you then set $y$ to it's minimal value, namely $y=x$: $\ \frac{xy}{x+y}\rightarrow\frac{xx}{x+x}=\frac{x}{2}=\frac{\text{min}(x,y)}{2}$. It's what you get if you take my answer and set $Y=1$. You could similarly set $y$ to its extremal value of 1 and obtain the lower bound expression $\frac{x}{1+x}=\frac{\text{min}(x,y)}{1+\text{min}(x,y)}$. But the simple value $\frac{1}{2}$ is a nicer/stronger way of giving a lower bound.

Comment: @NickKidman Nick

Comment: "Nick"? Btw. of course if you take the expression $\frac{\text{min}(x,y)}{1+\text{min}(x,y)}$ and set $\text{min}(x,y)=1$ in the denomiator, then you you get your function $\frac{\text{min}(x,y)}{2}$ back. Similarly the function $\frac{1}{1+\text{min}(x,y)}$ works too.

Comment: @NickKidman Sorry

Comment: @NickKidman ooooops, Nick, I don't know why I can't finish my typing previously. I hope I can make it this time. I wanna say that   I totally agree with your arguments, and thanks a lot for your prompt and kind input. I really appreciate your help :)